# Send email from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-mail

I need to send email from SQL Server SP. Until now I used `sp_send_cdosysmail`. Is it better to use `sp_send_dbmail`? And the main question - which mail server is used by `sp_send_dbmail` - is it configured somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Database mail depends on what server, profile is configured in Database Mail 
Ref: [Configure Database Mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-database-mail?view=sql-server-2017)

as for using `sp_send_dbmail`, see [sp_send_dbmail (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

This db mail functionality is available from SQL Server 2005.

See also [these example database mail configuration scripts](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/2009/05/17/database-mail-configuration/) by Dan Guzman.